# Increase PHP max_input_vars via web.config in IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-config, virtualhost

I have a simple wordpress web site under a windows hosting, I know that a Linux environment is better for wp but I need windows for another ASP.NET application. Anyway wordpress show me an error message about `max_input_vars` set to 1000 and this value should be 4000, I can't edit the `php.ini` then I would like to know if is it possible to set this value in the `web.config`, I know that in Apache it can be set in the `.htaccess` so I hope that can be done in the `web.config` as well.

Thanks in advice!

**EDIT**

I have found a solution: I create a `php.ini` file with `max_input_vars=4000` and I added it to wp-admin folder after that the error message disappear and checking the environment setting by PHP Settings wordpress plugin the `max_input_vars` value is 4000, I don't know if this is a best practice, but works, if someone has a better solution please explain it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four modes in which the PHP directives can be set:

- PHP_INI_USER
- PHP_INI_PERDIR
- PHP_INI_SYSTEM
- PHP_INI_ALL

Please have a look at how these are managed: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Each directive has one of these changeability modes defined and for that you could visit: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

As you'd see, the changeability attribute for directive `max_input_vars` is `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, meaning it can be overridden by adding a custom value in either of `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` (Apache) or `.user.ini`. Therefore, defining a new `php.ini` file to increase the limit of `max_input_vars` is just as fine as the other three workarounds.

Please remember though that, at times, some of the extensions that PHP would use might need to be re-enabled in custom `ini` files. For instance, I've at times run into problems with `pdo` and `mysqli` being considered as disabled, unless explicitly set in the custom file too, when using an override `ini` file.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time but i thought to post a solution for anyone who search about this issue.

1. Go to IIS and then from the right side there is an option to stop the server.. click on it.
2. Go to you default programs folder. Probably C: drive (C:\Program Files (x86)) then search for PHP folder.. probably you will find more than a version. choose the one you're using in wordpress.
3. Inside that folder you will find a file (php.ini) edit that file using notepad (you must start notepad using admin privilege).
4. It is a big file.. so search for (max_input_vars = 1000) and it is commented. so you have to remove the semicolon before the word max and then increase it to 4000. You may also search for memory_limit and increase it to 128m or more.
5. Save the file and make sure it is saved properly. try to open it again and make sure your changes are saved.
6. Return back to IIS and start the server.
7. Close the browser and open it again. Check your wordpress if the issue is cleared.

Good luck.